# Cannot Retrieve all record in my database using SQLSRV and PHP

Tags: php, sqlsrv

Im using PHP and SQLSRV.
My table record have month of October. but not displaying in my website

[Table record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lNoP.png) [Website Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALVMH.png)

It should be display all the records

```html
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $c WHERE [Code]=?";
$para = array($code1);
$opt = array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );
$stm = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql,$para,$opt);
    while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stm, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $code=$row['Code'];
        $lcode=$row['Loan Code'];
        $year=$row['Year'];
        $month=$row['Month'];
        $period=$row['Period'];
        
        
        echo"
            <tr>
                <td>$code</td>
                <td>$lcode</td>
                <td>$year</td>
                <td>$month</td>
                <td>$period</td>
            </tr>
        
        ";
        
    }
?>
```

Please help

Comment: First off, make sure the Code records have no special characters (or spaces). So check whether any COOP actually contains COOP\n , etc.....

Comment: there is no special character included it that text.
I dunno why it does not display in PHP Website but when i run it in MSSQLSMS it display it perfectly

Comment: Is the PHP db connection really pointing to the **same** MSSQLSMS which contains the Oct records ?

Comment: yes, it is the same database and same table

Comment: As a step of debugging, Please change using a query of SELECT * FROM $c WHERE Month='10' and see what happens please

Comment: I tried it but no display. but when I put SELECT * FROM $c WHERE Month='09' it display the month of September

Comment: I tried other table and it display all records except the last row. its weird

Comment: except the last row ???? Is it true that you have set some display records limit ? (or pagination ??)

Comment: yes. for example i have records from January to December in my database's table. but when I fetch the record using SQLSRV - PHP it display only  January to November.

Comment: i didn't set any limits for my codes or query

Comment: and when i query the exact record like "SELECT * FROM $c WHERE [Code]=101-0317-00893 and [Month] = '10' and [Loan Code]='COOP'"; and there is no record. but when I try it in MSSQLSMS and it display.

Maybe there is a problem in my SQLSRV - PHP version?

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't provide enough info.  After querying, there must be php code that is fetching the rows and either passing the results to frontend for rendering (if this is an api), or creating and echoing the html table in php with all the query results.  Is this code only rendering the first 10 rows?

Another observation - the website display shows a code and a loan code, but your table record as seen in your link only shows us a loan code.   Maybe code doesn't actually match.

Comment: sorry i got the wrong photo. I just re-upload it.
well in my php code it display all records except the last one. but when I try it in my sql server it display all the records perfectly